# Problem with currfile and the XePersian package

Tags: xetex, xepersian, currfile

I'm experiencing an issue where using the `xepersian` package breaks the functionality of the `currfile` package.

I have a main tex file and several subdirectories where I store my other files, and I have some helper macros that facilitate inclusion of these files in the subdirectories, and those rely on `\currfilebase` and `\currfilename`. But for some reason I'm always getting the main file's name even inside the other files. This only happens when the `xeperian` package is imported and without it everything works fine.

I created a small example that shows the behavior I'm experiencing:

main file content [`main.tex`]:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[parent]{currfile}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Vazirmatn}
\setdigitfont{Vazirmatn}


\begin{document}

\begin{latin}

    This is from the main file:

    currfilepath: \currfilepath

    currfilename: \currfilename

    CurrentFile: \CurrentFile

    CurrentFilePath: \CurrentFilePath

    \input{dir/inside_dir}

\end{latin}

\end{document}
```

create a `dir` directory in the above directory and inside it create this `inside_dir.tex` file:

```
This is from the inside\_dir file:

currfilebase: \currfilebase

currfilepath: \currfilepath

currfilename: \currfilename

CurrentFile: \CurrentFile

CurrentFilePath: \CurrentFilePath
```

compile in the main dir using `xelatex`:

```
xelatex main
```

and the output like below:

[image]

If I don't have the `xepersian` package (also remove the `latin` env), the output looks like below, which is the correct behavior:

[image]

Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: the bidi package redefines in biditools.sty the `\InputIfFileExists` command, this breaks the file hooks needed by currfile.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer so you mean this is a bug or just that these two packages are incompatible with each other? do you have a suggestion on getting the same info (i.e., the current file name) in an alternative way?

Comment: it is a bug/misfeature of bidi. It destroys a core LaTeX functionality (filehooks describe in ltfilehook-doc). Something like `\AddToHook{file/before}{\show\CurrentFile}` will do nothing if bidi is loaded.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Any alternative ways of getting the current file name?

Comment: make a bug report for bidi. They don't need to redefine \InputIfFileExists, they could use the hooks too and so stop the conflict with other packages.